# Custom UMN Mapserver WMS layer over Google API

Tags: google-maps, mapserver

I am using Google maps for my application. For getting some custom private map data, I have set up a WMS using Mapserver.
How can I add this Custom UMN Mapserver WMS layer over Google API (without using Openlayers)?

Comment: just a simple question, why don't you use openlayers?

Comment: Do you mean I can just change into openlayers without changing any coding? (coding for geocoding with Google API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it without using OpenLayers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354163/google-map-api-3-wms

The revelant code:

```
 //Define custom WMS tiled layer
 var SLPLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                    var proj = map.getProjection();
                    var zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom);
                    // get Long Lat coordinates
                    var top = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * 256 / zfactor, coord.y * 256 / zfactor));
                    var bot = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * 256 / zfactor, (coord.y + 1) * 256 / zfactor));

                    //corrections for the slight shift of the SLP (mapserver)
                    var deltaX = 0.0013;
                    var deltaY = 0.00058;

                    //create the Bounding box string
                    var bbox =     (top.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
                                   (bot.lat() + deltaY) + "," +
                                   (bot.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
                                   (top.lat() + deltaY);

                    //base WMS URL
                    var url = "http://mapserver-slp.mendelu.cz/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/local/slp/krtinyWMS.map&";
                    url += "&REQUEST=GetMap"; //WMS operation
                    url += "&SERVICE=WMS";    //WMS service
                    url += "&VERSION=1.1.1";  //WMS version  
                    url += "&LAYERS=" + "typologie,hm2003"; //WMS layers
                    url += "&FORMAT=image/png" ; //WMS format
                    url += "&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF";  
                    url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";
                    url += "&SRS=EPSG:4326";     //set WGS84 
                    url += "&BBOX=" + bbox;      // set bounding box
                    url += "&WIDTH=256";         //tile size in google
                    url += "&HEIGHT=256";
                    return url;                 // return URL for the tile

                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                isPng: true
            });


    map.overlayMapTypes.push(SLPLayer);
```

Comment: Yes, I already did it the same way. Thank you @Julien

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to code a bit, but it's not that difficult. If you follow these examples you can go through the process quite smoothly:

- http://khayer.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/open-layer-with-mapsever/
- http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Mapserver-layer-over-Google-Maps-td4956701.html