# How to perform Zoom to ImageMapType in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I am adding ImageMapType on Google Map using Google Maps API. Whenever ImageMapType is added then Map should zoom to that ImageMapType. I have read the ImageMapType reference and found out that any specific method however no luck.

I know that there is a method of Map.fitBounds() in which we have to give latlngBounds as a parameter however I am not able to get points from ImageMaptype. Please let me know is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have created ImageMapType object which is mentioned in below link.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/custom-umn-mapserver-wms-layer-over-google-api

How ever I don't know how to grab those bounding box of the last call to the GeoServer.

Comment: Please help me guys!!!